# How do i use function call properly. I am gonna do 2 batch python script. The one is in input the other one is output

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Lets say i have two batch python file.First one is `hello.py`. The next one is `john.py`

```
print('Hello world!')

print('What is your name?')

myName = input()

for Name in myName (1,10):

    print('It is nice to meet you, ' + myName)
```

And how i want to do function call myname at `john.py`. Does i need to run 2 batch python at the same time. I am also bit confusing at line `for Name in myName (1,10)`. What is meaning of that number.Please help me

Comment: `for Name in myName (1,10):` appears to be a mistake and will cause an error to be thrown. It is not clear what this line is intended to do.

Comment: So are any proper way. I am stuck at this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call function from the different file you need to import it.

E.g.

calculator.py

```
def greeting():
    print('Hello world!')
    print('What is your name?')
    myName = input()
    print('It is nice to meet you, ' + myName)
```

john.py

```
from calculator import greeting


greeting() # call imported function
```

As for loop statement it's invalid. Are you sure that it's correct?

Comment: I dont know its correct or not Can i know the correct way to do loop statement. Btw thank you.

Comment: First of all what are you trying to achieve? Just ask user for name and print it?

Comment: Yeah just simple python. As your information,I want to apply function call from my sensor reading

Comment: In this case you don't need loop. Edited answer.

Comment: Thats is. You are my hero. Any way can i contact you.